# Not able to get Configuration File to set GCM for Push Notifications in my iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am setting up GCM for Push Notification in my iOS app. I am following [GCM Documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start) to configure my app. In step 2. Get a configuration file, when I click on that blue button

[image]

I get a page to fill my app name and bundle ID of my iOS app. After filling the right info in the spaces, I continue and I get this error.

[image]

Any idea, why am I getting this error.

I am also not able to find where should I be uploading .p12 files of my APNS certificates to complete the setup.

Comment: Are the details you are entering not already created before make sure you are creating this for a real app. The section for .p12 comes up after this step

Comment: Looks like this is known issue and Google is working on it https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/107

Comment: This should be fixed now https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/107

Comment: That was my issue raised by me. Thanks anyways.